Is it OK to mix .NET framework versions?
Are there any potential pitfalls with using DLLs from .NET Framework 4.6 (in particular, System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll, System.Web.Helpers.dll, System.Web.Http.dll) as part of a .NET Framework 4.8 project?  A colleague is suggesting we do this, but I'm trying to convince them it's better to just work with 4.8.  Maybe I'm wrong, though.
